# Как подать данные на вход?

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети, хранение-данных

Хочу сделать RNN сеть по [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) и я хочу у вас спросить, как преобразовать список ниже во "входной вектор"?

```
10.03.17 9:20
10.03.17 9:24
10.03.17 9:28
10.03.17 9:39
10.03.17 9:56
10.03.17 10:13
10.03.17 10:31
10.03.17 10:48
10.03.17 11:29
10.03.17 12:09
10.03.17 13:20
10.03.17 13:26
10.03.17 13:29
10.03.17 13:33
10.03.17 13:40
10.03.17 13:41
10.03.17 13:46
10.03.17 13:48
10.03.17 13:52
10.03.17 14:18
10.03.17 14:23
10.03.17 14:47
10.03.17 15:08
10.03.17 15:39
10.03.17 16:02
10.03.17 16:34
10.03.17 16:44
10.03.17 16:51
10.03.17 17:07
10.03.17 17:29
10.03.17 17:42
10.03.17 18:37
10.03.17 18:55
10.03.17 19:22
11.03.17 9:14
11.03.17 9:19
11.03.17 9:21
...
```

И как это вообще будет выглядеть?

И ещё хотел спросить где можно узнать, что такое вектор состояний, матрицы параметров и вектор, а то там пишут без всяких ссылок и разъяснений как будто я знаю, что в них хранится.

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дату-время обычно преобразовывают в целое число ([UNIX timestamp или epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для нейронных сетей, как и для регрессий, важен этап подготовки данных перед обучением и нормальной работой. Все данные должны подаваться в числовом виде, а всё непохожее на числа нужно к ним привести. Например, как верно заметил @MaxU, дату и время обычно переводят в одно число.

Категориальные значения, которые могут быть в наличии, а могут не быть, приводят к нулям и единицам как входам отдельных нейронов. Например, два входа тэгов фильмов `[интересный, пугающий, боевик]` и `[красивый, интересный]` могут быть преобразованы так: `1 1 1 0`, `1 0 0 1`, где каждому числу соответствует интерпретация из списка `[интересный, пугающий, боевик, красивый]`.

Лично я на эту тему встречал мало теоретических материалов, зато много практических. Интересные ссылки:

- [Хабр: Краткий курс машинного обучения](https://habrahabr.ru/post/340792/) — есть раздел о подготовке данных: *Препроцессинг*.
- [Как я победил в конкурсе BigData от Beeline](https://habrahabr.ru/post/270367/) — помимо просто познавательного содержания, здесь тоже хорошо описана подготовка данных.
- [Scikit-learn: Preprocessing data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) — статья по теме с доков библиотеки `sklearn` для [python](/questions/tagged/python)
- [Хабр: Нейронные сети в картинках: от одного нейрона до глубоких архитектур](https://habrahabr.ru/post/322438/)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду так класифицировать входные данные?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy я имею в виду лишь то, что все данные на вход должны быть приведены в соответствующий вид, обработаны для эффективной работы обучающихся алгоритмов :) Это можно сделать разными способами, ссылки с примерами в помощь.